coil 2.6.0 does not resolve in KMP project
I have a problem in my KMP project. I would like to use coil to render images but I am currently unable to resolve the lib. I added it in the following places:
libs.versions.toml:
[versions]
coil = "2.6.0"

[libraries]
coil-compose = { module = "io.coil-kt:coil-compose", version.ref = "coil" }

build.gradle.kts (:shared):
androidMain.dependencies {
    implementation(libs.coil.compose)
}

Now the project is synced successfully but as soon as i try to use AsyncImage it wont resolve.
this is in my mainActivity:
AsyncImage(
    model = "https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/521/200/300.jpg?hmac=_MGlUtHw5IBlsNL7YvJ9lTMo4Ge605GWQwuKGxWIWU",
    contentDescription = null,
)

I can't import AsyncImage, does anyone have an idea what I'm missing?
I tried different versions, cleaning project, resetting caches and restarting
I expect being able to import AsyncImage

coil 2.6.0 does not support kmp but there is a beta version that does and it worked
fine in my project.
reference : https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/upgrading_to_coil3/
so in short change coil version with this one coil = "3.0.0-alpha06"
and it should work fine since there is no obvious problem in your implementation.
it also work with compose multiplatform so you can just implement in in the common main instead of android only :
with(libs.coil){
            implementation(compose)
            implementation(network)
        }


I've previously attempted this and have tried again now—thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I'm still facing the same issue where AsyncImage is not resolved. I specifically added version 2.6.0 to the Android module, adhering to our policy of avoiding beta libraries. However, neither coil = "3.0.0-alpha06" nor coil = "3.0.0-alpha01" (as mentioned in the documentation) seem to work.

did you implement coil network alongside with coil compose?

this is my current state in android module:
        androidMain.dependencies {
        implementation(libs.ktor.client.okhttp)
        implementation(libs.coil.compose)
    }


libs.versions.toml:
[versions]
coil = "3.0.0-rc01"
coilNetworkKtor3 = "3.0.0-rc01"
ktor = "3.0.0"
        
[libraries]
coil-compose = { module = "io.coil-kt.coil3:coil-compose", version.ref = "coil" }
coil-network-ktor3 = { module = "io.coil-kt.coil3:coil-network-ktor3", version.ref = "coilNetworkKtor3" }
coil-svg = { module = "io.coil-kt.coil3:coil-svg", version.ref = "coil" }
ktor-client-core = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-core", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-client-okhttp = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-client-darwin = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin", version.ref = "ktor" }

build.gradle.kts (:shared):
commonMain.dependencies {
    implementation(libs.coil.compose)
    implementation(libs.coil.svg)
    implementation(libs.coil.network.ktor3)
    implementation(libs.ktor.client.core)
}
androidMain.dependencies {
    implementation(libs.ktor.client.okhttp)
}
iosMain.dependencies {
    implementation(libs.ktor.client.darwin)
}
        

Example:
AsyncImage(
    model = "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/ae/2e/70/ae2e70f6660753cf4353ff443d3b1726.jpg",
    contentDescription = "im"
)

And add it to your AndroidManifest.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

        
        
        
        
        

